# Network Connection

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to call a webservice from an android app (Testing from an Emulator)

Now, i keep on getting "request time failed : java.net.SocketConnection : Address family not supported by protocol"

So, went to 'Browser' app of Android-Emulator and wasn't able to open any website

Also, then wrote a java code (J2SE) for network connection and got a "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Then looked here and there and guys had a say that some setting are to be done in eclipse and android-emulator to get the network connection going

Like in one of messages here --> "http://192.9.162.102/thread.jspa?messageID=10631928"

But how and where is what i am looking for ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks
Yogurt

Answer (score 0):

put this line`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` in Manifest.xml file. I think it will work for u.